# Passing route parameter to controller Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass a route parameter to controller, but I get this error : `Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\JurnalController::store() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\JurnalRequest, none given`

Below are the codes ..

Route :

```
Route::get('/edisi/{id}', 'JurnalController@store');
```

Controller :

```
public function store($id, JurnalRequest $request) {
            $input = $request->all();

            //Input PDF
            if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
                $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
            }

            $jurnal = Edisi::findOrFail($id)->jurnal()->create($input);

            return redirect('jurnal');
        }
```

So my question is how to pass the route parameter properly ? Thank you

new routes :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages/home');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('edisi', 'EdisiController@index');
    Route::get('edisi/create', 'EdisiController@create');
    Route::get('edisi/{edisi}', 'EdisiController@show');
    Route::post('edisi', 'EdisiController@store');
    Route::get('edisi/{edisi]', 'EdisiController@edit');
    Route::patch('edisi/{edisi}', 'EdisiController@update');
    Route::delete('edisi/{edisi}', 'EdisiController@destroy');
});

Route::get('/edisi/{id}', 'JurnalController@storejurnal');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('jurnal', 'JurnalController@index');
    Route::get('jurnal/create', 'JurnalController@create');
    Route::get('jurnal/{jurnal}', 'JurnalController@show');
    Route::post('jurnal', 'JurnalController@storejurnal');
    Route::get('jurnal/{jurnal}/edit', 'JurnalController@edit');
    Route::patch('jurnal/{jurnal}', 'JurnalController@update');
    Route::delete('jurnal/{jurnal}', 'JurnalController@destroy');
});
```

new storejurnal method :

```
public function storejurnal(JurnalRequest $request, $id) {
        $input = $request->all();

        //Input PDF
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
        }

        //Insert data jurnal
        $jurnal = Edisi::findOrFail($id)->jurnal()->create($input);

        return redirect('jurnal');
    }
```

Comment: put $id as second argument and Request $request as first

Comment: Tried it and got this error instead : Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\JurnalController::store() @Adamnick

Comment: are you using resource controller?

Comment: Yes I'm using resource controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using resource controller, the store method does not accept any other argument except the Request instance. Try changing the method name or remove the second argument. store() method be default accepts post requests not get requests. Either put your route on top of the resource controller or change the method name.

```
Route::get('/edisi/{id}', 'JurnalController@store');
Route::resource('jurnals', 'JurnalController');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know about this before, I will try it now, thank you! But I'm using the route parameter is just to retrieve the edisi id, if there is another way to get the id without using parameter can you please tell me

Comment: try changing the method name to something else i.e storeJurnal then everything  will be fine.

Comment: I rerouted everything, the routes shown on the question

Comment: Okay, wait a minute

Comment: I got this error to be exact : Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\JurnalController::storejurnal()

Comment: when you are using resource controller, just use 
`Route::resource('jurnals', 'Controller');` No need to define the routes yourself.

Comment: And try putting `Route::get('/edisi/{id}', 'JurnalController@storejurnal');
` on top of edisi routes. There is already edisi/{edisi} route which get attention before your route.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is:

```
    public function store(JurnalRequest $request, $id) {
        // your code
    }
```

If you receive an argument such as `Missing argument 2` as suggested in your comments, it means that either you aren't generating the routes correctly, or the url doesn't include the id segment.

Comment: Got the error. Here is the url that I'm trying to route : {{ url('edisi/' . $edisi->id) }} and in the browser it looks like this : 1mark/public/edisi/1 .. So I don't know what I did wrong :/

Comment: Is that the full url? It should look something like domain.com/edisi/1 - Not sure about "public" in there -sounds like your whole app isn't really configured correctly

Comment: localhost/1mark/public/edisi/1 that's the full url. Yeah maybe, I'm still a newbie in coding :D

Comment: or if I'm using virtual host it would look like this : 1mark.com/edisi/1

Comment: if you need to have 1mark/public in there, make sure you update your config file

Comment: How ? As I know the public folder contains data like css, js, htaccess and also web.config which is default from Laravel

Comment: And I'm only able to access the web through the public folder